# Why filter for a list of strings is causing error here

Tags: filter, d

I am trying to filter a list of strings to get only those which have a length more than one using following code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.algorithm;

void main(){
    auto slist = ["a","aa","b","bb","c","cc","dd",]; 
    slist = slist.filter!(a => a.length>1);     // does not work; 
    writeln(slist); 
}
```

However, it is creating error:

```
$ rdmd soq_map_filter_strlist.d
soq_map_filter_strlist.d(7): Error: cannot implicitly convert expression filter(slist) of type FilterResult!(__lambda1, string[]) to string[]
Failed: ["/usr/bin/dmd", "-v", "-o-", "soq_map_filter_strlist.d", "-I."]
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` returns a lazy range, which cannot be implicitly converted back to a `string[]`. You can either assign it to a new variable, or evaluate it to an array using `std.array.array`:

```
slist = slist.filter!(a => a.length>1).array;
writeln(slist);
```

— or —

```
auto slist2 = slist.filter!(a => a.length>1);
writeln(slist2);
```

Comment: Your first option `slist = slist.filter!(a => a.length>1).array;` does not work: `Error: no property array for type FilterResult!(__lambda1, string[])` . The second option `auto slist2 = slist.filter!(a => a.length>1);` is working.

Comment: You need to import `std.array`.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I wish the error message told me that.

Comment: In a way it does `cannot implicitly convert expression filter(slist) of type FilterResult!(__lambda1, string[]) to string[]` but I understand your frustration.  I had this same problem a few weeks ago and had to dig through forum posts to figure this one out.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to tell you "you need to import std.array" ??